# How do I click on a button in Selenium IDE using only the text associated with the button and not its position?

Tags: dom, selenium

this is the dom source of the button I want to click on
`<div class="footer clearFloat">
            <div class="left">
            </div>
            <div class="right">
                [P]
                [-575063738]
                [SB_XML]
                <input class="button" value="Next step" id="dpTransportResultSelectLink[7]" type="submit">
            </div>
        </div>"`

This is the x-path `"/html/body[@id='transport-results']/div[@id='master']/div[@id='master_center']/div[@id='page_content']/div[@id='contentPad']/form[@id='fare_5']/div[2]/div[2]"`

How do I frame my locator using "[SB_XML]", irrespective of the form Id?

Answer (score 0):

```
//*[contains(text(),'[SB_XML]')]/following-sibling::input[1]
```

I've tested it as an xpath but not in Selenium

lemme know how it goes

Comment: not sure if you've seen it but a great tutorial on xPath here... http://zvon.org/comp/r/tut-XPath_1.html